# Primary Key exception inserting into AspNetUsers table with Identity Framework Core 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I just setup a basic integration to Identity Framework Core 2.0.1 in my app. I've configured IdentityUser to use INT instead of STRING as its primary key as per this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-primary-key-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore2x).

I'm using code first with a blank database created via an initial migration.

The problem I'm running into is that when I create a user (I'm using postman), I get back the following exception:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'AspNetUsers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

I checked the value of appUser.Id when it is passed to UserManager.CreateAsync and it is definitely = 0 (which is the CLR default value for an Int property)

If I configure AppUser to use a String as a primary key (the default settings), the Id column is not set as an identity column and I get no error - the user is created without a problem with a GUID as the ID generated internally by the Identity framework.

From postman:

```
{
    "email":"someemail@comcast.net",
    "password":"Password123",
    "firstName":"Alex",
    "lastName":"Florin",
    "userName":"aflorin"
}
```

AppUser.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Driver.Models.Entities
{
    public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

AppRole.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Driver.Models.Entities
{
    public class AppRole : IdentityRole<int>    {

    }
}
```

IAppUserRepository.cs

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Driver.Repositories
{
    public interface IAppUserRepository<AppUser> 
    {
        Task Create(AppUser appUser, string password);
    }
}
```

AppUserRepository.cs

```
using Driver.DBContext;
using Driver.Models.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Driver.Repositories
{
    public class AppUserRepository : IAppUserRepository<AppUser>
    {

        private UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        protected DriverDbContext _dbContext;

        public AppUserRepository(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, DriverDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        public async Task Create(AppUser appUser, string password)
        {
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, password);

            //ToDo: if (!result.Succeeded) { }

            await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

AccountsController.cs

```
using Driver.Models.Entities;
using Driver.ViewModels.Identity;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Driver.Repositories;

namespace Driver.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AccountsController : Controller
    {
        private IAppUserRepository<AppUser> _appUserRepository;

        public AccountsController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, IAppUserRepository<AppUser> appUserRepository)
        {
            _appUserRepository = appUserRepository;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]RegistrationViewModel registrationVM)
        {
            if (registrationVM == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var appUser = Mapper.Map<AppUser>(registrationVM);

            await _appUserRepository.Create(appUser, registrationVM.Password);

            return CreatedAtAction("Create", new { id = appUser.Id }, Mapper.Map<RegistrationViewModel>(appUser));
        }
    }
}
```

RegistrationViewModel.cs

```
namespace Driver.ViewModels.Identity
{
    public class RegistrationViewModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ConfigureServices from Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DriverDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DriverDBConnection")));

    services.AddSingleton<IJwtFactory, JwtFactory>();

    services.TryAddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole<int>>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DriverDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    var settings = _config.GetSection("Authentication").Get<AuthenticationAppSettings>();

    // Configure JwtIssuerOptions
    services.Configure((Models.JwtIssuerOptions options) =>
    {
        options.Issuer = settings.JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer;
        options.Audience = settings.JwtIssuerOptions.Audience;
        options.SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(_signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    });

    // Specify the validation parameters to dictate how we want received tokens validated
    var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = settings.JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer,

        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = settings.JwtIssuerOptions.Audience,

        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = _signingKey,

        RequireExpirationTime = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };


    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

    }).AddJwtBearer(configureOptions =>
    {
        configureOptions.ClaimsIssuer = settings.JwtIssuerOptions.Issuer;
        configureOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
        configureOptions.SaveToken = true;
    });

    // Create an authorization claim policy to guard API controllers and actions
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("ApiUser", policy => policy.RequireClaim(Constants.Strings.JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, Constants.Strings.JwtClaims.ApiAccess));
    });

    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        // Password settings
        options.Password.RequireDigit = settings.Password.RequiredDigit;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = settings.Password.RequiredLength;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = settings.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = settings.Password.RequireUppercase;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = settings.Password.RequireLowercase;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = settings.Password.RequiredUniqueChars;

        // Lockout settings
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(settings.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = settings.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = settings.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers;

        // User settings
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = settings.User.RequireUniqueEmail;
    });


    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(
        options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    );

    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

    services.AddScoped<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<ILookupRepository, LookupRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IManagerRepository, ManagerRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<IAppUserRepository<AppUser>, AppUserRepository>();

}
```

The class declaration line for my DbContext (I'm not doing any custom configuration on the AppUser entity):

```
public class DriverDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int>
```

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem, but shouldn't `services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole<int>>()` be `services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>()`?

Comment: @IvanStoev. Your right, but that wasn't the issue. Though I think that would have bit me when I started adding adding roles. However, after a reboot of the PC due to a VS 2017 update and a recreation of the database (with no code changes - including keeping that IdentityRole in the AddIdentity call) it is now working, I have no idea why.